# Azure Recovery Services Vault with Terraform local provisioner

Tags: terraform, azure-powershell, terraform-provider-azure

Terraform doesn't provide options to change the Azure recovery Services Vault to use LocallyRedundant storage replication type. So I decided to use the PowerShell module to set this after the resource is provisioned. The command seems to be correct and works when it's manually invoked but doesn't when it's put in the provisioner. Any thoughts?

Terraform Version : 0.15 
Azurerm Version : 2.40.0

```
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "RSV"{
  name = "RSV"
  location = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = "RGTEST"
  sku = "Standard"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name ${azurerm_recovery_services_vault.RSV.name} | Set-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProperty -BackupStorageRedundancy LocallyRedundant"
    interpreter = ["powershell", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerShell scripts rely on the resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" that is fully created. In this case, if you include the [local-exec Provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) in a [null_resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource), run `terraform init` and `terraform apply` again, it works.

> Note that even though the resource will be fully created when the
> provisioner is run, there is no guarantee that it will be in an
> operable state

```
resource "null_resource" "script" {

    provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name ${azurerm_recovery_services_vault.RSV.name} | Set-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProperty -BackupStorageRedundancy LocallyRedundant"
    interpreter = ["powershell", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I decided to use a script to do this as Terraform doesn't have a database policy to provision. It wouldn't work now with the script. Do I need to try something different?
```
resource "null_resource" "script" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./AzureBackup.ps1 -vaultName ${azurerm_recovery_services_vault.RSV.name} -replication_type ${var.replication_type}"
    interpreter = [“powershelgl”, "-Command"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you provide the scripts in a .ps1 file as well as the parameters? If you want to execute multiple commands, you can use it like this `provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = <<EOT
      Write-Host "Hello ${var.name}"
      Write-Host "Bye"
  EOT

  interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
}` , see samples here https://kevsoft.net/2019/04/26/multi-line-powershell-in-terraform.html

Comment: The reason is that Terraform doesn't have all the modules to set the properties for RSV. For example the replication type, SQL backup policies. I am looking to set up RSV and define the policies in a script so no manual configuration is required. I was able to get it done with a script but it looks like it takes a while after provisioning to change this. Anyways, Thanks Nancy for all your help.